# How to fix 'callback is not a function error'?

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying an easy example using callback function, but it has some problem.

```
(function ddd () {
  const categories = [];
  const url2 = 'http://www.example.com';

  const callback2 = function (res) {
    console.log(res);
  }

  const callback = function (res,callback2) {
    res.products.forEach((el) => {
      categories.push({itemLabel: el.id, categoryLabel: 'gifts'});
    });
    callback2(categories);
  };

  getData(url2, callback);
})();
```

And console says `callback2 is not a function`.

I tried `console.log(typeof(callback2))` and it says `callback2` is a function.

So, what is the problem in this situation? When I just type `console.log(categories)` instead, it works well.

Comment: Where is your `getData` function?

Comment: I didn't write because it works well. Any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like this: 
Important is to pass the second callback already in the first function as a argument.

If you don't what to do this you can store the function in a global variable, but then it's not really a callback.

```js
(function ddd () {
  const categories = [];
  const url2 = 'http://www.example.com';

  const callback2 = function (res) {
    console.log(res);
  }

  const callback = function (res,callback2) {
    res.products.forEach((el) => {
      categories.push({itemLabel: el.id, categoryLabel: 'gifts'});
    });
    callback2(categories);
  };
 function getData(url, callback, callback2) {
    callback({products: [{id: 10}]}, callback2);
  };
  getData(url2, callback, callback2);
})();
```

With Global Callback2:

```js
(function ddd () {
  const categories = [];
  const url2 = 'http://www.example.com';

  const callback2 = function (res) {
    console.log(res);
  }

  const callback = function (res) {
    res.products.forEach((el) => {
      categories.push({itemLabel: el.id, categoryLabel: 'gifts'});
    });
    callback2(categories);
  };
 function getData(url, callback) {
    callback({products: [{id: 10}]});
  };
  getData(url2, callback);
})();
```

Comment: Okay I see. Hiding result and callback as a parameter, not global function is important

Answer (score 2):

You have to do something like this.

```
getData(url2, callback(result, callback2));
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to set callback's parameters

Comment: This can be dangerous, because I think the result will come out of getData. You should have both callback as a parameter and call the callback like this: ´callback(result, callback2)´ in the get data function. See my sample.

Answer (score 0):

as i seen you are passing callback2 as a param to function callback, then not load the global definition he uses his own scope definition of callback.

```
const callback = function (res) {
    res.products.forEach((el) => {
      categories.push({itemLabel: el.id, categoryLabel: 'gifts'});
    });
    callback2(categories);
  };
```

Removing callback2, from params method, will call callback2 defined previous , and dont find in own scope

Comment: Then how can I use properly?